# confused, is redis a in-memory only store that also rights to disk for backup/restore?

Tags: redis

confused, is redis a in-memory only store that also rights to disk for backup/restore?

if so, how long does a 16GB db take to write and read back to memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen on the [Redis README](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/README#All_data_in_memory,_but_saved_on_disk), all data is in memory but also stored on disk for persistency and backup value.

As for the 16gb database issue, it depends entirely on your server. For example;

- Does the server have any other I/O bound software running?
- What type of server is it? Shared? VPS? Dedicated?
- The hardware specifications of both the hard disk and RAM.

For those reasons, it is impossible to give you an accurate estimate as to how long reading and writing 16gb of data would take.

Honestly, if you're storing 16gb of data then Redis is most likely not the correct database program to be using simply because it is so heavy on RAM and disk space by design.